# Has 'find' similar capability as 'ls -visible pname'

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I can use "`ls -visible pname`" to find visible elements under '`pname`'.
But through '`find`', I can NOT find a way to find just visible elements. That is, '`find`' will always list hidden elements by the Config Spec also.

Does anyone know if '`find`' can find just '`visible`' elements under a specific '`pname`'??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)** has also the visible option, which should return the same result than `cleartool ls`.

```
–vis/ible
```

> Includes only those elements, along with their branches and versions, that are visible (have a standard path name) in the view.

This option has been introduced to speed up search on multiple vobs.

For one vob, as [kolslorr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389615/kolslorr) suggests in the comments of [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488577/has-find-similar-capability-as-ls-visible-pname/4496020#4496020), **`-cview`** is more appropriate, and I would combine it with **`-nxname`**:

```
–cvi/ew
```

> Modifies the set of objects selected by the –element, –branch, and –version queries (if any).
>   - If you did not specify `–version`, replaces each element and branch with the version that is currently in the view. (No substitution is performed on VOB symbolic links.)
>   - If you did specify **`–version`**, further restricts the subset to versions that are currently in the view.

```
-nxname
```

> Removes the extended naming symbol (by default, `@@`) and any subsequent version ID or branch path name from the name of each selected object.
>   Duplicate names that result from this transformation are suppressed.
>   In effect, this option transforms extended names into standard operating system names; it also transforms names of branches or versions into names of elements.

With those two options, compatible with a specific path, you should achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks VonC, but the -visible for find must be used w/ -all together that can NOT meet my request to just search a specific path. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

cleartool man find

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm

> Note: The find command is similar to
>   the UNIX and Linux find(1) command.
>   Only a limited set of the standard
>   find options are supported; the way
>   that commands are invoked on selected
>   objects (–exec and –ok options)
>   differs from find(1).

To answer your question to VonC, no, you are wrong. -visible does not need to work with -all, and you can use -visible to achieve exactly what you want to do.

Comment: cleartool> find . -visible  -type f -print
cleartool: Error: -visible and -nvisible are only valid with -all or -avobs.

Comment: you are right, it needs to be used with -all. My aplogies. how about adding additional selection options? e.g. -cview?